# Best way to set translated document title (HTML tag) in React with react-i18next

Tags: reactjs, react-i18next

At the moment I'm setting the document title in my function component like this:

```
useEffect(() => { document.title = 'My title' }, []);
```

I want my site to support different languages, so I've implemented `react-i18next`. 
I have buttons to change the language calling the function below. This changes the strings immediately on my web page.

```
const changeLanguage = (lng) => {
  i18n.changeLanguage(lng);
}
```

Changing the code mentioned earlier to the one below works (note the `t('...')` function), but only on page load. If I press my language buttons, the page title isn't updated.

```
useEffect(() => { document.title = t('My title') }, []);
```

How can I achieve this?

The same issue exists on strings passed to other components. For instance

```
// inside parent
<ChildComponent title={t('My title')} />

// inside child
<h1>{props.title}</h1>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your first problem is  that with the empty `Array` on `useEffect`, you tell React to only execute the code inside `onMount`, which means when you update your Language, this function doesn't get triggered. To fix that, use something like this:

```
useEffect(() => { document.title = t('My title') }, [lang]);
```

I couldn't reproduce the second problem. Make sure that if you change the language, the child prop rerenders. Test by using a simple `console.log('rendered');`